# UIButton is transparent when I don't want it to be

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have a button that I'm placing at the top corner of a custom UICollectionViewCell. For some reason, it is appearing translucent so that the border of the cell is being shown through the button when I would not like that to be the case.

In my CustomCollectionviewCell:

```
    lazy var favoriteButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star_white").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favoriteTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.isEnabled = true
        return button
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.mainWhite()
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        setupCellLayout()
    }


    fileprivate func setupCellLayout() {
        addSubview(favoriteButton)
        favoriteButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        favoriteButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        favoriteButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        favoriteButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        favoriteButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        bringSubview(toFront: favoriteButton)
    }
```

This results in the following:

[image][image]

Neither of these images are translucent. They have solid backgrounds so I am confused as to why they are displaying as translucent in the app. I originally thought that maybe they were being placed behind the cell so I added that call to `bringSubview(toFront: favoriteButton)` in setupCellLayout() but that didn't fix it.

I also thought that using `.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)` should have done the trick, but no luck.

Any Ideas as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Add views to contentView property of UICollectionViewCell

Comment: Do you have any view whose alpha is less than one

Comment: @Shruti no I do not

Comment: @aleixrr this doesn't fix it. Nothing changes actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIView`'s `subviews` are layers within the main `CALayer` of the view, and, theres obviously [no way to bring them above the layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551394/put-subviews-of-a-uiview-in-front-of-its-calayer), because thats like bringing them out of the view.

You can add a **background** subview with border, and add all other views in front of it.

Alternatively, you can insert a background sublayer, and apply border to this layer. However, please be ware not to `addSublayer`, as it will get added above the subviews, but to insert it at index 0 so its at the back

```
    let backgroundLayer  = CALayer()
    backgroundLayer.frame  = layer.bounds
    backgroundLayer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    backgroundLayer.borderWidth = 1.0
    layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, at: 0)
```

Another important point to look out for is to ensure the insert layer code does not get called repeatedly.

Comment: This was it. Concise and what I needed. Thank you.