# Why can't we put subviews of a UIView in front of its CALayer?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

As the title of this post, I found the answer regarding "Can we put subviews of a UIView in front of its CALayer" in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551394/put-subviews-of-a-uiview-in-front-of-its-calayer) post, but I cannot find the answer to *why* this is so. In my opinion, having the view as the subview of the layer's view only suggests "stronger" order between the subview and the layer. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

Each view is backed by a CALayer and the layer tree is a superset of the view tree.  Therefore every subview you add to a view has its corresponding layer added to its superview's layer.  Since its a child of the parent layer and layers are rendered from the top of thee tree down, you cannot change the render order.

Comment: so are you saying that the rendering of layers takes place after all the views are rendered? resulting in the layer appearing in front of the view?

Comment: No the views are never rendered.  The layer that backs the view is rendered.  A UIView is essentially a fusion of an input and an output (in object oriented terms it is a UIResponder and it has a CALayer).  The layer is entirely responsible for the rendering of the view and many familiar properties of the view actually just wrap the corresponding properties on the layer (isHidden, frame, bounds, center, etc)

Comment: but if the layer is rendered before the layer of the subview, shouldn't the sublayer be shown in front of the layer?

Comment: layers are rendered back to front  (painters algorithm) when going down the view tree and by sibling order or z position within the same node.  If you think about it this makes sense because if you have a tabbarcontroller it gets rendered first, then the navigation controller inside, then he view controller inside of that, and then a modal alert controller.

Comment: I am sorry but I still cannot understand why this is so. When I check the view hierarchy while debugging, the subview is in front of the layer. But in the simulator, the subview appears at the back of the layer. Why would the result be different?

Comment: Here's the thing: you don't need to understand *why*. All you need to know is: you can't mix subviews and sublayers. If you try to, the result is undefined. It might work today but fail to work tomorrow. Or it might fail to work today, but work tomorrow. Think of it this way: if you add `subviews`, you are ceding control of the `CALayer` tree to `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who struggled in this.
The reason your subview is under parent's layer might be because you add subview first, then add parent's layer latter.

What you did:

```
parentView.addSubview(childView)
parentView.layer.addSublayer(someLayer)
// This makes someLayer on top of subview.
```

What you want:

```
parentView.layer.addSublayer(someLayer)
parentView.addSubview(childView)
// This makes the subview on top of someLayer
```

To answer your question, the only thing that decide the z order between views are the order you adding either layer or view.
I think addSubview simply add sublayer to parent view under native implementation.